# Maven giving error Missing artifact

Tags: maven-2

I'm adding Google App Engine, Spring and Tiles2 to same project, for some reason Apache Maven gives this error.

```
Missing artifact org.apache.commons:com.springsource.org.apache.commons.collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
```

here is my pom.xml where i include dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.org.apache.commons.collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Dependency of type `pom`? Is this really what you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this by adding the following repositories:

```
<repository>
    <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
    <name>EBR Spring Release Repository</name>
    <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
</repository>
<repository>
    <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
    <name>EBR External Release Repository</name>
    <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
</repository>
```